# Need Help - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating the flag of Djibouti for an assignment although I'm encountering quite a lot of problems. First of all, I tried adjusting the size of the star and it was all so confusing. I need the star to be very small, while still holding its form. But I gave up so I then resulted to making the flag bigger, but the white triangle is clinging on to the top blue part of the flag so it looks a little odd. Also, the star is sticking to the white triangle.

All in all, this is very confusing and I'd really appreciate some help!

[here's a picture of the flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS1mB.png)

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.white {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #27B6D6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.green {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #AEE749;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}


.triangle-right {
 border-top: 90px solid transparent;
 border-left: 140px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 160px
}

.star-5-points {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: -120px 0;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;    
  color: red;
  transform: rotateZ(35deg)   ;
}

.star-5-points::before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -45px;
  left: -65px;
  border: 30px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 80px solid red;
  transform: rotateZ(-35deg)   ;
}

.star-5-points::after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 3px;
  left: -105px;
  border: 100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 0 solid;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  color: red;
  transform: rotateZ(-70deg)   ;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DjiBouti</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="blue">
        <div class="triangle-right"></div>
        <div class="star-5-points"></div>
      <div class="white"></div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh boy the home work :)

Comment: We don't give our personal emails out, but how about you post your code in a snippet?

Comment: Boy that is confusing, tried to just half the values, but there are also positional values that need to change. Gave up

Comment: @StefanBob I'm in a graphic design class and this is just a small unit but it's so difficult. Stars are the worst.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Sorry about that! The code along with a pic of the flag are in now.

Comment: In reality I would just use an image xD otherwise just have to mess with the values you are so close yet so far

Comment: @StefanBob I was trying to refrain from using a picture but at this point, I could care less lol. How would I layer the image of the star onto the flag though? On JSFiddle the image shows up above the actual flag and the image doesn't show up. I put it into Brackets.io and both the flag and the image don't show up. However, if I put the image of the star in by itself on both programs, it shows up??

Comment: What using a unicode character for the star instead?

Comment: @NateWhittaker I need the star to be red. Would that be possible with unicode?

Comment: Yes, you can style it as you would any other alpha-numeric character. At least for the non-emoji chars.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that star is very finicky. Here's what I came up with:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.white {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.blue {
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #27B6D6;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.green {
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #AEE749;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}


.triangle-right {
 border-top: 90px solid transparent;
 border-left: 140px solid #fff;
 border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
    border-left-width: 160px
}

.star-5-points {
box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: -96px 0;
    border: 33px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-bottom: 19px solid red;
    color: blue;
    transform: rotateZ(32deg);
}

.star-5-points::before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -13px;
    left: -26px;
    border: 13px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-bottom: 22px solid red;
    transform: rotateZ(-35deg);
}

.star-5-points::after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 1px;
    left: -36px;
    border: 29px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-top: 0 solid;
    border-bottom: 22px solid red;
    color: red;
    transform: rotateZ(-70deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DjiBouti</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="blue">
        <div class="triangle-right"></div>
        <div class="star-5-points"></div>
      <div class="white"></div>

    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```